LaTeX doesn't look like LaTeX
Needs["Splines`"];
SelfIntsctArc = 
  Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{-0.76, 
       1.61}, {2.645, -0.79}, {-2.195, -0.77}, {1.09, 1.58}}]}];
names = Graphics[{Text[Style["x", 17], {0.1877, 1}], 
    Text[Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]", 17], {-0.55, 1.3}], 
    Text[Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 2]", 17], {0.95, 1.3}], 
    Text[Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 3]", 17], {0.1877, 0}]}];
Show[SelfIntsctArc, names]


What it looks like:
$\gamma_1$" />
In the code above I used TeX input for the labels of some arcs. However, they don't look like LaTeX input at all. It looks more like the letter v with a number next to it instead of $\gamma_1$. I've installed the latest MaTeX package. How do I make the labels look more like actual LaTeX?

In the code you presented you did not use MaTeX at all...

I don't see any reference to TeX in your code, so not sure what you're referring to when you say you "used Tex input". But even so, the appearance of text depends on font choice, so why don't you just specify the font you want? You can probably get Computer Modern somewhere if you want the standard TeX aesthetic. I just tried Palatino, and it looks like a clearer gamma to me.

Why do you include the Bezier curve??

Did you mean to do something like Needs["MaTeX"];
MaTeX[Subscript[[Gamma], 3]]? See the documentation for MaTeX[]`.

@lericr thank you. I couldn't find that font, but changed it to cambria math, and now it looks way better.

@DavidG.Stork For fun

Bad reason.....


code
<<MaTeX`

Needs["Splines`"];
SelfIntsctArc=Graphics[{BezierCurve[{{-0.76,1.61},{2.645,-0.79},{-2.195,-0.77},{1.09,1.58}}]}];
t1=MaTeX["x",Magnification->1.2];
t2=MaTeX["\\gamma_1",Magnification->1.8];(*Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 1]",17]*)
t3=MaTeX["\\gamma_2",Magnification->1.8]; (*Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 2]",17]*)
t4=MaTeX["\\gamma_3",Magnification->1.8]; (*Style["Subscript[\[Gamma], 3]",17]*)

names=Graphics[{Text[t1,{0.1877,1}],
                Text[t2,{-0.55,1.3}],
                Text[t3,{0.95,1.3}],
                Text[t4,{0.1877,0}]}
      ];

Show[SelfIntsctArc,names,ImageSize->400]

